# symfony: uniform url without user's culture

Tags: symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4

I am considering the possibility of working with a merchant in my region who offers payment gateway services.
The specific merchant works with the "Payment Page" concept, i.e a specific uri of my site e.g `http://www.mysite.com/culture1/cart/index` will be authorized from the merchant side in order to proceed with the user's payment.

My site is built with symfony 1.4 and supports `i18n`, so all of my routes have the culture embeded in the url (/:sf_culture/...)

i.e for `culture1` (which is the default one):

```
http://www.mysite.com/culture1/cart/index
```

for `culture2`:

```
http://www.mysite.com/culture2/cart/index
```

However if the payment goes from the second url it will simply fail on the authorization from the merchant site.

So, is there any way in symfony to create a uniform url (using routing) for a specific action in a specific module without embedded culture information by keeping at the same time the user's culture?

In this scenario the goal would be to be authorized using the following url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/cart/index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rout with culture for example:

```
contacts:  
  url:   /:sf_culture/contacts
  param: { module: static, action: contacts }
  requirements: { sf_culture: (?:uk) }
```

Same rout without culture:

```
contacts:  
  url:   /contacts
  param: { module: static, action: contacts }
```

Just set default culture for each user when :

```
    homepage:
      url: /
      param: { module: static, action: about}
      requirements: { sf_culture: (?:uk }

    localized_homepage:
      url: /:sf_culture
      param: { module: static, action: about}
      requirements: { sf_culture: (?:uk) }

apps/frontend/modules/static/action.class.php

    public function executeAbout(sfWebRequest $request)
  {


   if (!$request->getParameter('sf_culture'))
        {
        if ($this->getUser()->isFirstRequest())
            {
            $culture = $request->getPreferredCulture(array('uk'));
            $this->getUser()->setCulture($culture);
            $this->getUser()->isFirstRequest(false);
            }
        else
            {
            $culture = $this->getUser()->getCulture();
            }

            $this->redirect('localized_homepage');
        }
  }
```

**// apps/frontend/lib/myUser.class.php**

```
public function isFirstRequest($boolean = null)
{
  if (is_null($boolean))
  {
    return $this->getAttribute('first_request', true);
  }

  $this->setAttribute('first_request', $boolean);
}
```

If the user enters the link, which contains no culture, it's okay,importantly, that it was previously determined. Just try)

You can also set culture in action:

```
$this->getUser()->setCulture('uk');
```

**Update:**

If the sf_culture variable is not present in the request, it means that the user has come to the / URL. If this is the case and the session is new, the preferred culture is used as the user culture. Otherwise the user's current culture is used.

It from Jobeet tutorial.([click](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/19))

Comment: Yes. This will do the job. Thank you. BTW I didn't understand the purpose of the `else` statement in the `executeAbout` method. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: In the point where I mentioned in my first comment there is a `$culture` variable being set and never read...Is there any reason for this?

Comment: `$culture = $this->getUser()->getCulture();`This is not necessarily, unless you want to get the current user locale  and use it somehow, for example in some query, or perhaps somewhere in the view.You can also just make:`$this->getUser()->setCulture($request->getPreferredCulture(array('uk')));` And it is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You just have to add it to your `routing.yml` without the `:sf_culture`. The culture is kept on the user's attribute. So that `:sf_culture` is only needed if you change your language and SEO.

Comment: Yes you are right. I haven't realized the existence of this variable in the user's session attribute. You and the debug toolbar shed light on this. However I marked denis281 answer as accepted because he was more thorough and detailed. Nevertheless you got my upvote ;)